# Can I use Microsoft WebMatrix to access SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I created a development web database following these instructions: http://www.w3schools.com/website/webpages_database.asp

```
var db = Database.Open("Northwind"); 
var query = db.Query("SELECT CompanyName,City,Country FROM Customers");
```

The example code provided uses Microsoft WebMatrix to access the database. At a later time, however, I would need to access the a SQL Server 2008 production database by a connection string.

Can Microsoft WebMatrix be used for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions on how to do it using SSMS for Sql Server 2008 R2

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209(v=sql.105).aspx